# Which countries, regions, or cities have set a date to ban the sale of gasoline and diesel vehicles?

Tags: transport, cars, greenhouse-gas-emissions, law

This week, the UK announced that sale of gasoline and diesel cars will be banned by 2035. This new policy moves the date up by five years, and also includes hybrid vehicles. From 2035 on, only electric or hydrogen-powered cars will be sold. ([From the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-51366123).)

The Rocky Mountain Institute, in a [blog post](https://rmi.org/britains-ban-on-gasoline-and-diesel-cars-is-a-game-changer-for-evs/) about the new policy, included this statement:

> The UK is joined by dozens of other countries and cities around the world that have set similar goals to ban the internal combustion engine (ICE) cars between 2025 and 2050. These regions all recognize there is virtually no way to achieve meaningful carbon reductions in transportation without a major contribution from the light duty vehicle sector.

They did not provide any details. **Which countries, regions, and cities have set a target date to ban the sale of gasoline and diesel vehicles? What are the specifics of the plan?**

Answer (score 6):

The best list is probably wikipedia: [Phase-out of fossil fuel vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-out_of_fossil_fuel_vehicles)

There is a good review from the World Economic Forum [here](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2017/09/countries-are-announcing-plans-to-phase-out-petrol-and-diesel-cars-is-yours-on-the-list/), dated 2017, which discusses some of the different approaches taken, which I've summarized here:

- UK: Ban production of petrol and diesel cars by 2040 (since changed to 2035);
- France: Ban sale of petrol and diesel cars by 2040;
- Norway: Policy to phase out petrol and diesel by 2025;
- Netherlands: Target for all cars to be emission free by 2030;
- Germany: Resolved to ban petrol and diesel by 2030 (but hasn't passed the ban);
- India: Government wants all new cars electric by 2030;
- Canada: Sales of new fuel-powered cars and light trucks will be banned by 2035 [(source)](https://www.reuters.com/world/americas/canada-ban-sale-new-fuel-powered-cars-light-trucks-2035-2021-06-29/);

There is more recent information from the International Energy Agency in their [Global EV Outlook 2019](https://www.iea.org/publications/freepublications/publication/GlobalEVOutlook2017.pdf), which includes information on some strong measures being taken at the state level in the US and Canada.